# Wireshark does not recognize adapter

Tags: wireshark

I am attempting to capture data using Wireshark and am getting this error message:

"The capture session could not be initiated on interface '\Device\NPF_Loopback' (Error opening adapter: A device which does not exist was specified.  (433))."

So I went into Wireshark Options and am attempting to add an Input Capture Interface. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This question is a great question for the [Wireshark Forums](https://ask.wireshark.org) instead as it is not about coding.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't fix it at all until today.

What I did was install an older stable version of Wireshark (v2.6.11 it is) and it works now.

So try this out and I hope it'll work for you as well.